# $_FILES returning undefined index

Tags: php, file-upload

In my html i have this:
`<input type="file" id="apkfile_uploader" name="apkfile_uploader_name" class="form-control-file">`

and the form have `action="path"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"`

when i am trying to upload the file using php the `$_FILES` returns `undefined index error` for this line of code:  `$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["apkfile_uploader_name"]["name"]);`
the error goes as follows:`Undefined index: apkfile_uploader_name`

Comment: try debugging the `$_FILES` variable by var_dump it to see whether the file is actually uploaded or not

Comment: I have tried ```$file= $_FILES["apkfile_uploader_name"]["name"];
            echo var_dump($file);``` and it returned an error of  ` Undefined index: apkfile_uploader_name` on this line `$file= $_FILES["apkfile_uploader_name"]["name"];`

Comment: not like that, try var_dump( $_FILES ) where you will see the array and check for "apkfile_uploader_name" . if not there then your file is not uploading in server

Comment: okay , this code `echo var_dump($_FILES["apkfile_uploader_name"]["name"]);` also result in an undefined index error but it returned NULL, so no file is read?

Comment: you don't need to echo var_dump, just write ' var_dump( $_FILES ); ' and see don't add any array index like previous comment

Comment: it returned and empty array `array(0) {
}`

Comment: so your file is not uploading in the server , check your code

Comment: thank you for your help i figured that the only thing preventing the code is js

Answer (score 0):

I first thought the problem was caused either from the form or from the php but it turned out that the js preventing the page was the cause.
Here is the code that worked for me:

```
jQuery(document).on('submit', '#wnform_settings', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(element) {
                if (element.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = ((element.loaded / element.total) * 100);
                    percentComplete = percentComplete.toFixed(0);
                    $("#progressBarback").val(percentComplete);
                }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).prop('action'),
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'text',

        beforeSend: function() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                $("#progressBarback").val(0);
            }, 1000);

        },

        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(ajaxOptions + "\r\n" + thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```